# Xamarin forms relative layout position stacklayout at bottom

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, uwp-xaml, xamarin.uwp

I would like to position a Stacklayout at the bottom on top of an image using a relative layout using Xamarin forms using xaml only. The xaml pretty much looks like this.

```
<RelativeLayout>
    <Image />
    <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
        <Label Text="Dark Mode" />
        <Switch />
        <Label Text="Light Mode" />
    </StackLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

What X and Y constraints should my StackLayout have so that it is positioned on top of the image and at the bottom of it.Also added an image which describes the result i expect.

**Expected :**
[image: RelativeLayout]

I did try to give **RelativeLayout.XConstraints** and **RelativeLayout.YConstraints** to both the image and the stacklayout , but not able to figure out what values to use to get the desired result.

Comment: You could use `Grid` instead of `RelativeLayout`.

Comment: @EgorGromadskiy I did already try that approach , but my image does not stretch inside the grid even though Aspect is set to AspectFill.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can have a StackLayout across the whole picture and inside it another StackLayout that will be placed at the bottom:

```
<RelativeLayout>
  <Image Aspect="AspectFill"
         RelativeLayout.WidthConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent, Property=Width}"
         RelativeLayout.HeightConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent, Property=Height}"/>
  <StackLayout
         RelativeLayout.WidthConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent, Property=Width}"
         RelativeLayout.HeightConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent, Property=Height}">
      <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalOptions="EndAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="Center">
          <Label Text="Dark Mode" />
          <Switch />
          <Label Text="Light Mode" />
      </StackLayout>
  </StackLayout>
```

Comment: This is not a such good approach, because you loose events such as scrollView on map for example.